# How can I make all buttons on a page the same width via CSS?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have 30 buttons of different sizes and I want to set the width of all at once through CSS.  But I haven't been able to get it to work right.

[insert example of failed CSS code here]

But it doesn't work.  For example, the following button doesn't follow the above rule:

[insert minimal, complete HTML example here that illustrates the issue]

Comment: Hey, for some reason your question was getting flagged recently.  Either [edit] to update or just revert my edits.  Thanks.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a button class in your css

```
.button
{
    width: ____px;
}
```

and then in your .aspx add `cssClass="button"` to your ASP buttons (I assume they're asp.net controls?)

Comment: This is what I was thinking for sure and it will work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do this explicitly, you can simply add the `!important` attribute, although this will guarantee that regardless of location or source, the `width` property will be overridden, so be sure that you definitely want to apply that style.

```
button {
    width: XXXpx !important;
}
```

### EDIT

To make the above style only apply to one HTML page, as per your request, you can change the HTML for that page slightly, giving an `id` to your `<body>` tag, and then targeting buttons only when they appear below that `id`.

#### HTML

```
<body id="page_title">
```

#### CSS

```
#page_title button {
    width: XXXpx !important;
}
```

Comment: I only want it to apply to this one file.

Comment: Do you mean to only one HTML page, or to one CSS file?

Comment: the selector should be `button, input[type=button], input[type=reset], input[type=submit]`!

Comment: @nightfirecat - only one html page

Comment: Alright, see my edit - basically, you'd just add an ID to that `<body>` tag, then select that in the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

For input element

```
INPUT[type="submit"] {
    width: XXXpx;
}
```

For button

```
BUTTON {
    width: XXXpx;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your buttons have something unique in common (ie. they're all have the class name of "buttons"), you can just use a CSS selector to set their width property.  ie.

```
.buttons {
    width:100px;
}
```

There are a number of different selectors you can use to target them, and keep in mind you can have multiple classnames on each html element by putting a space between them. ie. `<div class='nav button'></div>` will respond to both the .nav and .button definitions.